# How to use Codeigniter cache feature user role base

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have see web page caching feature of codeigniter and it's useful for achieve maximum performance.

I have applied this feature as per describe in this [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/caching.html) and it's working fine.

But in my system some feature enable/disable as per user role. can anyone help me how to use cache feature user role base ?

After applied this feature I have tested using admin user and normal user. Cause of caching normal user see all the admin feature links.

Is there any way to remove cache when user log-out ?

Comment: i think its entirely wrong to use this cache feature in relation with user specific content

Comment: @sintakonte: you are absolutely right but I have required because some pages are load in every page and it 's taking too much time like header, footer,sidebar menu so...

Comment: take a look @ http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html?highlight=cache#CI_Cache just store your partials with this method and your user specific content should be always dynamic - i'm wondering what costs so much time in your static content - or in other words - how much time needs your application?

Comment: not a static content sidebar menu render as per user role. means it's dynamic

Comment: i think in this case you have to save your content on a per user base p.e. user with id 1 gets $contentMainPage1 or something like that if you really want to cache the output - but like i said its a mistake. i've a project with about 300 controllers right now and my response times are in a range between 0.06 and 0.30s - if your times are above this times i think your bottleneck is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

You can remove cache by using below function on end of each controller
`function no_cache(){
        header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0',false);
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
    }`

Comment: But when user again open same page then it will take same time so cache  feature not useful as per you answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage to get the data in all pages...

```
For EX: localStorage.user_role = "SubAdmin";
```

and you can get it using javascript

```
alert(localStorage.user_role);
```

but it is not preferble to store any data in localStorage or cache...
But as it's your requirement...Use above example as a reference ,And i hope it may help you.

And one advantage of localStorage is....
Clearing cache has no effect on HTML5 localStorage or sessionStorage (but clearing cookies does!)